# Small cleanup of the [faq-proposal] tag done

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I've just cleaned up the [faq-proposal](/questions/tagged/faq-proposal) meta tag. This isn't a big deal, but I'd like to leave a record of what changed and why a few very old questions just got edited. This tag had two kinds of questions:

- questions which were proposed for the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.
- very old questions which were proposing changes to our help documentation, which several years ago involved a document called the "FAQ".

The second type has been retagged with [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center), consistent with [the same tag used on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help-center).

[faq-proposal](/questions/tagged/faq-proposal) now exclusively features questions that at least one person thinks would be a good fit for our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), and I've added a description that explains this. (The Meta Stack Exchange tag equivalent is [faq-proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).)

Comment: Thanks for doing that, and it's reminded me to [faq] the ones that clearly have leading answers and have gone cold.